# Too many "dots" in dash after 18.04 --> 20.04.1 upgrade?

Tags: unity-dash

I noticed, that after leaving applications group in dash, dots representing pages in dash are multiplied. Normally there are only 3 dots. Anybody else having this behavior? Found the fix?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You've clicked on the `Show Applications` in the dock, and the dots on the right side of the screen are NOT to show open applications, but rather, to show which scrollable page of application icons that you're looking at.

Comment: I enter dash by Super+A
Open application group
Click outside of the application group area to close it|
Dash disappears and appeared again with many dots on side

Comment: Use the mouse SCROLL wheel to page through all of the applications. Use the SUPER key to close it.

Comment: @heynnema
Please read the question. there are  4 times more dots on the right side of the dash, than it should be.

Comment: What do you see when you use the mouse wheel scroll and scroll down to the 4th/5th/etc dots?

Comment: Something changed in my system. Behavior back in normal. Topic no more valid.